# Al extraer texto de una pagina web con selenium python, me aparece el siguiente error en la salida, solo aparece signos de interrogación

Tags: python, selenium

```
for elementPost in elementsPost:
    title = elementPost.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='post-title']").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    print(title)
    description = elementPost.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='post-body']").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    print(description)
    print("\n")
time.sleep(2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aparece signos de interrogación y no el texto en si.

Comment: Y el texto en sí, ¿no estará en coreano que tu terminal no sabe renderizar?

Comment: https://unaj.edu.pe/es/blogs-grid esta es la pagina y esta en español, no se a que se debera que no pueda formatearlo el texto en la salida

Comment: Bueno, no es coreano, pero casi. Están usando caracteres unicode matemáticos para mostrar negritas, y tu terminal no lo sabe mostrar. Por ejemplo, el nombre de Yudith aparece como  (`b'\\U0001d5ec\\U0001d602\\U0001d5f1\\U0001d5f6\\U0001d601\\U0001d5f5'`). La buena noticia es que tu programa funciona.